# R how to remove rows in a data frame based on the first character of a column

Tags: r, string, dataframe

I have a big data frame and I want to remove certain rows from it based on first char of a column being a letter or a number. Sample of my data frame looks like a below:

```
y<-c('34TA912','JENAR','TEST','34CC515')
z<-('23.12.2015','24.12.2015','24.12.2015','25.12.2015')
abc<-data.frame(y,z)
```

Based on the sample above. I would like to remove second and third rows due to the value in y column in second row and third row starting with a letter instead of a number. Characters written in Y column could be anything, so only way I could filter is checking the first character without using any predefined value. If I use grep with a character, since other rows also contain letter, I could remove them aswell. Can you assist?

Comment: See `help(regex)`.  Also, welcome to SO.  The site guidelines suggest that you please show us your research efforts in attempting to solve the problem yourself.  See [ask] for more.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We can use `grep`.  The regex `^` indicates the beginning of the string.  We match numeric element (`[0-9]`) at the beginning of the string in the 'y' column using `grep`.  The output will be numeric index, which we use to subset the rows of the 'abc'.

```
 abc[grep('^[0-9]', abc$y),]
 #        y          z
 #1 34TA912 23.12.2015
 #4 34CC515 25.12.2015
```

Comment: Akrun, I have a quick question. In my data there are rows which are just numbers. For example I have data in some rows like '2254', '12345678'. Normally the data in any row should contain at least one letter. So a normal data should like this: '34ABC21','23AA41'. How can I remove the rows with just numbers?

Comment: @OğuzhanAkdeniz  Try `y<-c('34TA912','JENAR','TEST','34CC515', '2398'); grepl("[A-Za-z]+", y) & grepl("[0-9]+", y)` or `grepl("^.*[0-9]+[A-Za-z]+.*$|.*[A-Za-z]+[0-9]+.*$", y)` to get the logical index.